# VS 2010 + IIS: Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7

I have recently started to received this message.

```
 Unable to start debugging on the web server.
 The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running
```

Does anyone know what this means?

I created my virtual directory via Properties on the project, and clicking Create Virtual Directory. ANd in IIS I can see it, I run VS 2010 with Admin Privs.

The Application pool in .Net 4.0

Any help really appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT**

I managed to get it working but its a good workaround really. Basically there was another website setup i.e. Default Website where all my apps goes which was started and running.

And there was another website (which was stopped!) that was for installanywhere.. But it was stopped! ... I removed the site completely and now it works

Can vs 2010 not figure out which one to connect to or something?

I presumed if its stopped then it wouldn't try and connect..

Very confused, Anybody know of alternative work around?

Comment: If i changed the vs 2010 project to use the inbuilt web server then everything works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error message after reinstalling VS2010. In my case all application pools in the IIS where remapped to run 4.0, so VS2010 was unable to figure out which pool to attach its self to during debugging. The solution in my case, was to manually delete few pools and remapping my older pools back to .net 2.0. I finally ended up, only having 2 pools pointing towards .net 4.0 (integrated  and classic) and 2 pools running .net 2.0 (integrated and classic).

Comment: Thanks - if another site is also mapped to same IP / Port, even if it is stopped disabled, it confuses VS.