# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have a web site (not a solution) type project in VS2010.
I also have this folder configured as a web site in IIS7.  I can browse to my site fine when I navigate to http://myproject.local

This proves IIS is serving the site ok.

Now when I try and run the project from VS2010 so I can debug, I get the following error:

**Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running.**

I have the site properties set to invoke the custom server (IIS) at the correct URL.
What is the reason for Visual Studio implying that the IIS work process for the launched URL is not running, when clearly IIS is server the site.

Answer (score 106):

This is a very intermittent behavior. I usually get this issue once or twice a month. Following steps would resolve the problem easily.

Before trying anything else, try **iisreset**

> > **Step 1:** >> Open Run (Ctrl +R)  >> type **iisreset**

If this doesn't work, then try step 2.

**Step 2:**  Open task manager >> **Processes** >> select Process and **right click** >> **end task**. This should kill IIS worker process.

[image]

If step 2 doesn't work for you then go to step 3.

**Step 3:** Task manager >> Services and restart the IISADMIN.

> Some of you might not have IISADMIN service so If you can see IISADMIN, right click and restart.

[image]

Comment: Cool ! Thanks a ton !

Comment: I don't find IISADMIN service. what could be wrong?

Comment: First of all, I was having this issue and your post helped a lot, so thanks :) Second, I wanted to point out for me personally I didn't have anything called IISADMIN under Services, but the first step still solved the issue, so in case anyone else runs into that, just the first step is enough to fix it.

Comment: After first step if you use iisreset then issue will be solved. To reset iis type "iisreset" in run window.

Comment: Step 2 worked after step 1 (_maybe don't need step 1_)

Comment: In my case iisreset didn't help, didn't find that process running, but windows reboot helped. Just in case someone needs it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 73):

I managed to solve the problem using the following:

- Task Manager -> delete IIS process(es) (stopping IIS in the manager didn't work)
- Go into IIS manager
- Restart IIS service

Comment: Thanks, deleted IIS process, in the IIS manager restarted the web application.

Answer (score 7):

i was able to solve the problem as follows:

1. opened a command prompt with administrator privileges and performed IISRESET
2. opened IIS Manager, stopped the IIS Server
3. cleaned the solution in Visual Studio
4. started the IIS Server again
5. rebuilded the solution in Visual Studio

cannot say what exactly caused the problem, but with these steps i was able to get it working again without a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with IIS 8 (Windows 8 x64) and an ASP.NET MVC application hosted in IIS.

The solution for me was:

1. clean the solution in VS 2012
2. start IIS Manager
3. stop IIS (this took 3 minutes, I have no clue why)
4. restart the computer
5. rebuild the solution
6. start debugging

I'm not sure which steps are required, I (fortunately) can't reproduce the problem. I don't know if that matters but I have 7 app pools and 3 different web sites in IIS, but 2 of the 3 are stopped at the moment.

Comment: For my case it was solved by running the VS as an administrator

Comment: just type iis reset in a cmd prompt, it will restart the IIS process which was stopped by a failure/bug

Answer (score 4):

I had multiples site configured to different Application Pools. As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3957572/6556519), I have removed all other sites (which were stopped) to only keep the one that I needed.

As mentioned by StuartLC : "if another site is also mapped to same IP / Port, even if it is stopped disabled, it confuses VS"

Hope it will help...

Comment: I had same problem. It seems that another apppool was causing the problem. I removed stopped websites and apppools and worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue and fixed it simply by recycling the app pool.

Comment: This did fix the issue in the question, but when I subsequently debugged my code (using the VS debugger) my breakpoints did not work (though they looked okay). Following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33931620/4051181) resolved the issue fully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The solution was to check hosts file. There should be no rules for "localhost".

Answer (score 1):

On my computer the issue was that I had 2 bidding to the same site and **Visual Studio** could not contact the proper web site.

I stop the "other" web site (not the one I was triyng to Debug) then the **Debug**
action could start.

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable Windows Authentication to fix it.

Turn on window feature: Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security -> Windows Authentication.

Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, navigate to your web site, double-click Authentication icon under IIS category, and enable Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.It solved when I changed Application Pool in IIS Advanced Settings from **Classic .NET AppPool** to **DefaultAppPool**.

Answer (score 0):

Just end task the IIS Worker process resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using a command line
Open an elevated command-line window.
At the command prompt, type net stop WAS and press ENTER; type Y and then press ENTER to also stop W3SVC.
To restart the Web server, type net start W3SVC and press ENTER to start both WAS and W3SVC.

reference
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9339773-7eff-4313-a14b-00f2b9f94ead

or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ms957500(v=cs.70).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) Close browser.

2) Enter in CMD: **iisreset**

Answer (score 0):

end task all iis process and restart iis. 
its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the stop/restart IIS processes worked for me, instead the problem I had was that there were 2 sites both running on localhost:80 in IIS Manager, even if 1 was stopped it still conflicted with VS debugging.

So I just changed the stopped sites binding to :8080 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to be because I changed my password last week.

I went into my IIS pool -> Advanced Settings -> Navigated to Identity and entered in my updated credentials.

Once I input this, the error went away and I was able to debug again.

[image]

[image]

[image]