# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929480/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-iis-worker-process-for-the-launc)

Hi,
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET webforms and IIS7.

I'm getting this error:

Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running.

When I launch the site I can see w3wp.exe process running.  So what is the problem?

Comment: Please update the original question with more information instead of posting a duplicate with less.  Editing your question will bump it back to the top of the active list.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the dupe? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this KB from Microsoft and see if it helps:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814717

Also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee%28VS.71%29.aspx

Similar questions answered here:

[VS 2010 + IIS: Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846827/vs-2010-iis-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-iis-worker-proces)

[Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929480/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-iis-worker-process-for-the-launc)

Comment: Why was this question closed down? The more people ask the question the more maybe Microsoft would flipping sort this error out!!